# Regex: how to only allow integers greater than zero

Tags: regex

I have tried the following to only allow integers in my text box, this works great but it allows a zero in there. Is there anything else I can add to prevent a zero being added?

```
\d+
```

Answer (score 7):

This will allow 10 but not 01, and it will allow only numbers consisting of digits, i.e., no periods or minus signs...but also no plus signs, scientific notation etc.

```
^[1-9][0-9]*$
```

Answer (score 5):

A minor variation is this:

```
/\d*[1-9]\d*/
```

That would allow leading zeros.

Comment: Good. But one should keep in mind that in some contexts, integers with leading zeroes are used to represent octals.

Comment: how 10 is working in this case as second match is [1-9] ?

Answer (score 4):

If you are not concerned about negatives and silly numbers like `07`, this will do:

```
/[1-9]\d*/
```

For a more robust solution, I suggest converting the matched string to integer and check if it fulfills your criteria.

Comment: a simple ^ anchor would deal with negatives

Comment: @Alex K: ... unless the number may appear in the mid of a string. To answer that (and similar problems), the question has to give much more details.

Comment: @EduardoCuomo: Yes, it does ... as does the original regex in the question (`\d+`). I'm addressing only the "prevent a zero" part. Everything else is unclear in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
^([1-9][0-9]+|[1-9])$
```

Example: http://regexr.com/3annd

Tested with:

```
0
10
01
11
00
1
100
```

Comment: Isn't that equivalent to `^[1-9][0-9]*$` and `^[1-9]\d*$`, just a bit less straight-forward?

Answer (score 1):

```
^(0*[1-9][0-9]*)$
```

This will allow "silly" numbers like 007 as well, but not 0 or 000 or an empty string.

Note that `\d` matches also digits from other character sets like `٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩`. See: [\d is less efficient than [0-9]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16621778/880990).

`^` denotes the start, `$` the end of the string. Together they ensure that the whole string is matched.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(\d{2}[1-9])$
```

matches with:
from 001 to 999
example
001
099
999

does not match
000
01
0